# Rank the data with more than one factor and different proportion

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I have a mysql table stored the employee's performance, which include four factor :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84375/1

Now i would like to rank the employee by different proportion.

all the factor are "the higher the better".

factor2 can be negative number.

the proportion of them are :-

factor1 : 45%

factor2 : 25%

factor3 : 15%

factor4 : 15%

i don't have any idea how to do it,

but if it is impossible to done with only sql,

my server side language is PHP.

Comment: What are you measuring each value against to get the percentage?

Comment: What is this "proportion" and how do you calculate it?

Comment: can you clarify what you want to do ?

Comment: my math is not good, and i see this method from some competition,
which the rule is said there is four difference measurement, they hold 45%,45%,15%,15% of the total score.

Comment: my knowledge of statistics is not good, the problem may be related to 
http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Composite_scores

Comment: And the problem is all four factor has diffidence "max-score". if they are all score like "xx/100", than it is ok. dosse anyone know how shall we process data like this in statistics way ?

Comment: i have missing one thing on the question : factor2 can be negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work as you want?

SELECT *, (45*Factor1 + 25*Factor2 + 15*Factor3 + 15*Factor4)/100 as Performance FROM EmployeePerformance ORDER BY Performance DESC

edit: after reading the comments i believe this is what you want

```
select *,
  ( 45 * Factor1 / (select SUM(Factor1) from EmployeePerformance)
   + 30*Factor2/(select SUM(Factor2) from EmployeePerformance)
   + 15*Factor3/(select SUM(Factor3) from EmployeePerformance) 
   + 15*Factor4/(select SUM(Factor4) from EmployeePerformance)
  ) / 100 as Performance
FROM EmployeePerformance 
ORDER BY Performance DESC
```

Comment: the problem is all four factor has diffidence "max-score". if they are all score like "xx/100", than it is ok. dose anyone know how shall we process data like this in statistics way ?

Comment: What does the max-score mean? Should we measure .45 * Factor1 / Factor1MaxScore?

Comment: I looked at your wiki-link and this is the same thing as talked about there (regression-weighted)

Comment: that can be a way.... maybe 
0.45 * Factor1 / (sum of all Factor1). But i don't know is there some Shortcoming of it.

Answer (score 0):

you look for this ?

```
SELECT * , (45*Factor1 + 25*Factor2 + 15*Factor3 + 15*Factor4)/100 as proportion 
FROM EmployeePerformance 
ORDER BY id
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c881/5)

Comment: the problem is all four factor has diffidence "max-score". if they are all score like "xx/100", than it is ok. dose anyone know how shall we process data like this in statistics way ?